# Addressing a vector inside vector of vector pointers

Tags: c++, vector

To implement an open hash table in C++, I thought I'd define a vector that contains pointers to vectors containing data. For the sake of simplicity, let's say I want a hash table that can store `int`s. I assumed I needed a `vector< vector<int>* >` for that.

The resulting data structure could look something like this:

> [index 0] 8, 6, 2
>
> [index 1] (empty)
>
> [index 2] 9, 12, 15, 28, 1

I could have created a static array of `vector<int>` pointers, but I wanted to be able to add more indices as I go along.

To write out elements, I wanted to do something like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myHashtable.size(); i++) {
  cout << "[index " << i << "]";
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < myHashtable[i]->size(); j++) {
    cout << " " << *(myHashtable[i])[j];
  }
  cout << "\n";
}
```

This code doesn't compile. What's the correct way to address `*(myHashtable[i])[j]`?

Comment: Consider using a [`boost::ptr_vector`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) for the outer vector, to easy memory management.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(*myHashtable[i])[j]
```

Subscript operator (`[]`) binds more tightly than dereference (`*`) (see http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/operator_precedence).  Therefore you need to force the binding by using parentheses.

Incidentally, you could write you inner loop thus:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = myHashtable[i]->begin();
     it != myHashtable[i]->end(); ++it)
{
    cout << " " << *it;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `(*(myHashTable[i]))[j]`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply (*myHashtable[i])[j]

Answer (score 2):

`(*myHashtable[i])[j]` because `[]` operator has higher precendence then `*` operator.